# Saving instances when created by an iterator - Python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, iteration

I would like to use an iterator to generate a number of instances of a class, but I also want to be able to assign a variable to each individual instance that is created in this process.  Is there a way to do this?  Below is my current code and the result is that I am able to print the data I am looking to have access to, but the objects created are overwritten each time it iterates.  Ideally I would like to assign separate variables to each dictionary that is generated from the iterator so that I can apply additional functions to them.  So instead of just one layerObject at the end I would have 3 different layerObjects if the spreadsheet contained data in 3 rows.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this without pre-defining the number of objects that will be created, however I would like this to remain flexible enough that it could generate (and save) as many objects as there are rows of data.  Is there a way to do this?

```
import openpyxl

layerFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('\xxx/xxx/xxx.xlsx')
layerSheet = layerFile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

class Layer:

    def __init__(self, layerNumber):
        #initialize list to hold layer data
        self.layerData = []
        self.keyFields = []

        #read layer attribute data from excel file
        for columns in range(1, layerSheet.get_highest_column()+1):
            cellData = layerSheet.cell(row = layerNumber + 1, column = columns).value
            cellFields = layerSheet.cell(row = 1, column = columns).value
            self.layerData.extend([cellData])
            self.keyFields.extend([cellFields])

    #creates dictionary that contains layer information
    def layerContainer(self):
        self.layerContainer = dict(zip(self.keyFields, self.layerData))
        return self.layerContainer

#reads the file for all layers in the excel file and creates 
for rows in range(1, layerSheet.get_highest_row()+1):
    layerObject = Layer(rows)
    print(layerObject.layerContainer())
```

Comment: That's not an iterator.. Also, you're assigning a value to the method, then returning it; which means if you call the method again, it won't work because it'll be a `dict`, not a method. What are you trying to do, at a higher level than you've already said? Or another question; what code do you want to be able to write that you can't write now?

Comment: To expand on what @Cyphase said - ```self.layerContainer = ...``` ; the name of this attribute is the same as the method that is creating it.

Comment: You need to do the same thing you did with `self.layerData` and `self.keyFields`: create a `list`. As you loop through, `append()` each new `Layer` object to the `list`.

Comment: Thanks all, I think each of you hit on points similar to Anand.  Cyphase, as you might be able to tell I am new to programming so might not have all the terminology down.  What would you call the for loop at the end of my code if not an iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to use some kind of a data-structure to store the created `Layer` objects , something like `list` or `dictionary`.

Then you can later access the list or dictionary (iterate over them) to get the layer objects. Example -

```
layer_list = []
for rows in range(1, layerSheet.get_highest_row()+1):
    layerObject = Layer(rows)
    print(layerObject.layerContainer())
    layer_list.append(layerObject)
```

Then to access your layer objects -

```
for layerObject in layer_list:
    print(layerObject)
    #Do whatever you want with it.
```

---

Also, ideally you should not use the same variable name as the function name , especially inside a class, since when you do -

```
def layerContainer(self):
    self.layerContainer = dict(zip(self.keyFields, self.layerData))
    return self.layerContainer
```

you are overring the `layerContainer` function with a dict, hence after one call to this function, you can no longer access layerContainer as a function.

Comment: Thanks Anand, lightbulb moment with creating a list of objects.  That will totally work.  Thank you for the tip on naming as well.